# How to bind application on startup to named system semaphore?

Tags: c++, mfc, frame

How to bind application on startup to named system semaphore? If an instance of application is already running bindig will fail. Falling to binding the semaphore will lead to bring the already runnig instance to front.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Tried to make sense of the questions.

Comment: i am new in mfc apologise i just want that when SDI application once minimize after that when i click on icon of application it has to start from that instance, should not create a new instance of application.